# Javascript how to identify button clicked

Tags: javascript

I have a page with many articles. Each article has a delete button. How can I identify the button clicked for the article?

Currently I have this:

```
<button type="button" id="delete-article" class="btn btn-small btn-danger">Delete</button>

$('#delete-article').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log('Test delete article');
});
```

This logs 'Test delete article' according to the number of articles on the page.

Comment: you can provide a different data attribute to each html button and then in onClick you can get the data attribute for which button is clicked, in the event. Read about data-attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to establish relation between article and corresponding button, one way to implement is by using HTML5 [data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) attribute. 
assign `data-articleId` to article id in button element and when you click the button you can access which button was clicked by using Jquery `.data()` function.

```
<button type="button" data-articleId='123' class="btn btn-small btn-danger delete-article">Delete</button>

$('.delete-article').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).data('articleId'); //will return 123;
    console.log('Test delete article');
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried to use the data attribute, and I am able to get it to log the correct id, however it outputs this for every article on the page.

Comment: i guess you have multiple button on your page, instead of assigning same id to each button you should use class attribute to target the button. i have updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can attach the event on button and use [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) object to refer the currently clicked button:

```js
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="delete-article" class="btn btn-small btn-danger">Delete</button>
<button type="button" id="delete-article-2" class="btn btn-small btn-danger">Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use your event variable to get the target of the event (that is, the element responsible) and from there get its id, like this:

```
let btnId = event.target.id;
```

However, for that to work properly you should assign unique ids to your buttons. If you want to provide other data (or you don't want to use id) you can append custom attributes, like `data-value` or similar, and use it like this:

```
let myValue = event.target.getAttribute('data-value');
```

Comment: Thank you, I can add the article id to the element id to make it unique. But then how can I call the JavaScript function?

Comment: You could add a unique class to all of your buttons, like `my-button` or `custom-button`, then assign the event using a class selector like `$('.my-button').on('click', function(e) ...` but you have to make **sure** you only use that class on your buttons

Answer (score 0):

If all the buttons have this markup

```
<button type="button" id="delete-article" class="btn btn-small btn-danger">Delete</button>
```

Then the DOM sees them as just one button, you should find a way to attach unique ids to your buttons

Answer (score 0):

You can get an object of clicked button then you can get any details from that object like an index or whatever you want.

```
$('#delete-article').click(function(){
    console.log($(this));
    console.log($(this).index());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly achieve it by using the JavaScript.

```js
document.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
  console.log(e.target.id)
})
```

```html
<button type="button" id="delete-article1" class="btn btn-small btn-danger">Delete1</button>
<button type="button" id="delete-article2" class="btn btn-small btn-danger">Delete2</button>
<button type="button" id="delete-article3" class="btn btn-small btn-danger">Delete3</button>
<button type="button" id="delete-article4" class="btn btn-small btn-danger">Delete4</button>
<button type="button" id="delete-article5" class="btn btn-small btn-danger">Delete5</button>
<button type="button" id="delete-article6" class="btn btn-small btn-danger">Delete6</button>
<button type="button" id="delete-article7" class="btn btn-small btn-danger">Delete7</button>
```